# How can i reset after files uploaded, jQuery.filer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using jQuery.filer for upload images. After successful request i want reset the form and clear the fields. How can I reset the image upload field?

My code

```
$('#image_upload').filer({
            limit: 3,
            maxSize: 3,
            extensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'psd'],
            changeInput: true,
            showThumbs: true,
            addMore: true,
            captions: {
                button: "Choose Images",
                feedback: "Choose Images To Upload",
                // feedback2: "files were chosen",
                // drop: "Drop file here to Upload",
                removeConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to remove this file?",
            },

        });
```

I tried,

```
$('#image_upload').filer('reset');
$('#image_upload').filer('refresh');
$('#image_upload').filer('destroy');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://gerardbalaoro.github.io/jquery.filer/#documentation

you should be able to use:

```
var filerKit = $("image_upload").prop("jFiler");
filerKit.reset();
```

to reset the input